# How to install pip3 on a linux docker-image using dockerfile

Tags: python, pip, dockerfile

I am building a Linux docker-image using a docker file in which there is a command to install python3-dev and pip3. The python3-dev is getting installed perfectly but pip3 is getting errors. What is the proper syntax for installing pip3

RUN apk add pip3 install --upgrade pip

Error is:

Step 3/3 : RUN apk add pip3 install --upgrade pip                                                                                                                        ---> Running in 71181984d781                                                                                                                                           fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                            fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.10/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                       ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:                                                                                                                                         install (missing):                                                                                                                                                        required by: world[install]                                                                                                                                           pip (missing):                                                                                                                                                            required by: world[pip]                                                                                                                                               pip3 (missing):                                                                                                                                                           required by: world[pip3]                                                                                                                                            The command '/bin/sh -c apk add pip3 install --upgrade pip' returned a non-zero code: 3

Answer (score 1):

`pip3 install` is its own command. You don't need `apk add`

However, extending the existing python alpine image might make it easier

And the recommended way would actually be

```
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```